# Can not use CV_32UC1

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to store 32 bit unsigned integers in a matrix.

When I try to create the matrix:

```
Mat frameV(frameT1.rows-2*R, frameT1.cols-2*R, CV_32UC1 );
```

this gives compilation error :

```
error C2065: 'CV_32UC1' : undeclared identifier
```

Although CV_8UC1 works but I need CV_32UC1.

I am using MSVC 2010 and OpenCV 2.4.3.

Comment: There is no CV_32U defined in OpenCV. You can use CV_32S when creating a matrix, while use the elements as unsigned integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such type as `CV_32UC1`. This is because OpenCV does not support 32 bit `unsigned int` type. The largest integral type supported by OpenCV is 32 bit `int` which can be specified by the `CV_32SC1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a complete list of matrix data types.

http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2010/09/opencv-basics.html

According to that article, 32 bit depth matrices should be signed or float. OpenCV does not support unsigned 32 bit depth matrices.